# How to open Internet Explorer for the desktop from command line in Windows 8?

Tags: command-line, windows-8, internet-explorer, powershell

There are [two different Internet Explorer versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh771832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Windows 8. I would like to open Internet Explorer for the desktop from command line.

We can run it via <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> → `iexplore`, but I would like to run it from the command prompt or PowerShell. Can it be done?

Comment: For normal command line just use "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" for the 64bit one or "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" for 32bit one

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using PowerShell, I found that [`Invoke-Item`](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849794.aspx) was a key command:

```
Invoke-Item "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
```

Other factors:

1. The command only worked for me when I gave the full path to iexplore.exe.
2. You may run into script execution problems if you save the instruction and run from a .ps1 file. In that case, execute the following from an elevated PowerShell prompt:

   ```
   Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
   ```

Comment: Note sure if Start-Process would not be better; again we need the full path: Start-Process "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"

Answer (score 1):

The tried and true method in every relevant version of Windows:

```
iexplore.exe google.com
```

will open IE and navigate to google. I use invoke-item for some things, but this can be done from the run box (which the OP stated) which saves key strokes. It also works in cmd and powershell, b/c iexplore's path is in the PATH env variable.

Comment: iexplore.exe google.com
iexplore.exe : The term 'iexplore.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a pat
h was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ iexplore.exe google.com

I'll give the time to correct the answer before downvote :D